# Django - How do i calculate the sum of a field in a queryset

Tags: django, sum, django-queryset

Using DJANGO
I have a simple model that has fields Customer_ID, Date, Product, Total_price. I want to display them in groups by Date so all prices on that date are shown grouped
eg

> `28 April 2020
>
>      Crisps  £1.20
>
>      Cheese  £1.40`
>
> `29 April 2020
>
>       Crisps  £1.80
>
>       Cheese  £3.40`

How do I then show total price under each date (eg £2.60, £5.20)
Here's what I tried in my html, all good displaying in groups but last  tag for calculating sum doesn't work:

```
{% regroup results by Date as new_list %}
    {% for Date, results2 in new_list %}
        <div class="track-row">
            <span class="track-item track1">{{ Date }}</span>
               {% for data in results2 %}
                   <div>
                        <span class="track-item track3">{{ data.Stock }}</span>
                        <span class="track-item track5">£{{ data.Sell_price }}+vat</span>
                        <span class="track-item track4">{{ data.Quantity }}</span>
                        <span class="track-item track5">£{{ data.Total_price }}+vat</span>
                    </div>
               {% endfor %}
               <h6 class="title4">£{{ data.Total_price__sum }} + vat</h6>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

In my views.py I created a queryset with all totals:

```
total = Quotes.objects.values('Customer_ID', 'Date').filter(Customer_ID=customer_id).\
    annotate(total_price=Sum('Total_price')).order_by('-Date')
```

and this works fine and gives me the correct totals, but how do I show these results alongside my html.

I tried:

```
       {% for data2 in total %}
           <h6 class="title4">£{{ data2.total_price }} + vat</h6>
       {% endfor %}
```

which works great but just shows all totals
Can I select each record from above queryset and put it next to my corresponding list or is there another way to show sum of my prices in each group
Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to implement a simple custom filter that takes the list as parameter and returns the sum.

*sample layout*

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        myapp_extras.py
    views.py
```

*myapp_extras.py*

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def sum_total_price(value):
    sum = 0
    for v in value:
        sum += v.Total_price
    return sum
```

Then in the template, first you load the filter,

```
{% load myapp_extras %}
```

and finally just use it,

```
<h6 class="title4">£{{ result2|sum_total_price }} + vat</h6>
```

[Django Docs - Custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Comment: Thank you so much, that has saved me a lot of headache. Works perfectly now

Comment: Glad it helps you!